# C++ : Help needed to debug generic linked list

Tags: c++

Below is my attempt at generic representation of a linked list, where i pass an example with integers. I know that the problem is with how i am assigning next (through the add_to_list function), but after staring at screen for 2 hours i still have no clue what is wrong. Could someone guide me through it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/** Class Definition here */

template<typename  T>
class Linklist
{
    struct node
    {
        node(T value,node* next=NULL):value(value),next(next) {}
        node* next;
        T value;
    };
    node* head;
    node* curr;

public:
    Linklist(node* n=0):head(n) {}
    ~Linklist();
    void add_to_list(T value, bool x=1);
    void print();

};

/** Class destructor */
template<typename T>
Linklist<T>::~Linklist()
{
    node *ptr ;
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        ptr=head;
        head=head->next;
        delete ptr;
    }
}


template <typename T >
void Linklist<T>::add_to_list(T x, bool z)
// bool basically means if to add the element to beginning or end of list, 1 for end.
{
    node* k=new node(x);
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        k->value=x;
        k->next=NULL;
        head=curr=k;
    }
    else
    {
        k->value=x;
        k->next=NULL;
        if (z==1)
        {
            curr->next=k;
            curr=k;
        }
        else
        {
            k->next=head;
            head=k;
        }
    }
    delete(k);

}

template<typename T>
void Linklist<T>::print()
{
    node* ptr= new node(1);
    ptr=head;
    if (ptr==NULL)
    {
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"reached here \n " <<"pointer is"<<ptr->value<<"\n next is"<<ptr->next;
        while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<ptr->value<<"-->";
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    Linklist<int> *intlist=new Linklist<int>();
    intlist->add_to_list(20,0);
    intlist->add_to_list(344,1);
    intlist->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output are you seeing?

Comment: You missed the actual problem.

Comment: @andy256, just the first element (i.e 1-->)
I checked with step by step analysis that the next function returns 0 everytime but cant see why.

Comment: @chris , I know i missed something but dont know what lol . can you help?

Comment: `node* ptr= new node(1);
    ptr=head;` is a bad sequence. You insta-leak memory because nothing refers to the memory you allocate anymore. Also, your main function does not need a pointer. A normal object is fine (and better).

Comment: And you got an answer !

Comment: Your `node` constructor already initializes the member fields so you don't have to say `k->value=x;` and `k->next=NULL;` again in your `add_to_list` function.

Comment: @chris , fair enough. Whats the advantage of a normal object? Does it saves up on memory? i guess it has to do with automatic garbage collection.  Sorry i m very new to C++ programmming so my base concepts are not strong enough yet.

Comment: C++ doesn't have garbage collection...

Comment: If you want a linked list you can use the standard provided ones (std::list, std::forward_list). They are widely used so you wont find many bugs and they are also very optimized. In general it makes more sense to make use of existing functionality rather than implementing it yourself.

Comment: @Dennispersson , i am just learning data structures and also C++ programming so i think its a better habit to get familiar with how things work at grassroot level. Of course I agree you with you that after a certain good level of understanding of things I will use them directly :)

Comment: @AkashRupela, Not ouch, it has better. Objects are destroyed and memory freed at known times (when an object goes out of scope or `delete` is called). A normal object means you don't have to destroy it manually (which can be impossible to do safely at times).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `delete(k);` after you add it to the list so the system can use the memory for new objects.
You should not delete it since you are still using that memory

When you don't delete it the output is:

```
reached here
pointer is20
next is0020882020-->344-->
```

not related to the bug, but you should avoid `new` when you can, such as your `main` code:

```
Linklist<int> intlist;
intlist.add_to_list(20,0);
intlist.add_to_list(344,1);
intlist.print();
```

Comment: You are correct that calling `delete` it the problem but the compiler doesn't "put junk" in the node after deleting it. It just makes the memory available to be used for something else.

Comment: Okay. So i will basically call the deconstuctor to free that memory. Learnt so many concepts in so little time so its a little load on the brain :)